# XmlHttpRequest - post JSON - json string too many quotes (i think)

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I created a standard function to POST a data object

```
post = function(url, data){

// Return a new promise.
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    req.onload = function() {
        // This is called even on 404 etc
        // so check the status
        if (req.status == 200) {
            // Resolve the promise with the response text
            resolve(req.response);
        }
        else {
            // Otherwise reject with the status text
            // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
            reject(Error(req.statusText));
        }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
        reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    var jayson = JSON.stringify(data);
    req.send(jayson);
    });
};
```

when I call this function with data = {key: value, anotherKey: value}, the jayson variable looks like this:

```
"{"key":value, "anotherKey":value}"
```

In the end, the data does not reach the server (the request does). I get a 200 status back, so on the server all is well.

**(yes, it needs to be a POST - no, I do not want to use jQuery)**

What's going wrong in my function, that it does not send my data?

Comment: "In the end, the data does not reach the server (the request does)" — this sounds unlikely. Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Examine the request. Is it a POST request? Does it have the request body you expect?

Comment: Whatever `JSON.stringify` reruns is valid JSON.

Comment: Why you think that data does not reach the server ? Other words how you check it ?

Comment: in Network tab, I klick on the request - I can't see it defined as POST
i do see the Request Payload

Comment: @AlisherGafurov - I check in the $_POST object - nothing there

Comment: @JohanPotums — "I check in the $_POST object  - nothing there" — Well, there wouldn't be. You're sending JSON, not a standard form encoding type.

Comment: So where do I find it?

Comment: See the duplicate question.

Comment: @Quentin ah - I found it after letting the response come back - it is definitely POST - not sure about the Request Body though - the Request Payload (Chrome Developer tools) gives correct values

Comment: @Quentin - thanks for your input - I had no idea and the resources about posting JSON do not mention this